# Finding all possible combinations from an indeterminate amount

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Given a list; `List<List<SomeType>>` where the inner list could be any size at all, and the outside list would be the size of a variable passed to the function, I need to find all possible combinations of the containing elements.

Because my explanation is probably pretty poor, here's an example input and output.

Input:

```
[
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h'],
    ['i']
]
```

Output:

```
[
    ['a', 'c', 'g', 'i'],
    ['a', 'c', 'h', 'i'],
    ['a', 'd', 'g', 'i'],
    ['a', 'd', 'h', 'i'],
    ['a', 'e', 'g', 'i'],
    ['a', 'e', 'h', 'i'],
    ['a', 'f', 'g', 'i'],
    ['a', 'f', 'h', 'i'],
    ['b', 'c', 'g', 'i'],
    ['b', 'c', 'h', 'i'],
    ['b', 'd', 'g', 'i'],
    ['b', 'd', 'h', 'i'],
    ['b', 'e', 'g', 'i'],
    ['b', 'e', 'h', 'i'],
    ['b', 'f', 'g', 'i'],
    ['b', 'f', 'h', 'i']
]
```

I'm absolutely stumped as to how to get this done. I simply cannot wrap my head around it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The total permutations can be quite large - I would suggest writing an iterator generate them without storing them. It’s pretty trivial, you just need an array of counters, the size of the outer list, then you just “count”. Increment the first counter - does it exceed the size of the first list? Reset it and increment the next counter (or “carry”). When the last counter exceeds the size of the last list, you’ve done em all.

Comment: [Guava offers this as a library function](https://guava.dev/releases/23.5-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-) - it’s open source. So you can either use it or take inspiration from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation. It seems to work fine. I used a String[][] as an input, but you can change it as needed.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * This method nests (input.length) for loops to build the desired output.
     * @param input The input, change the data type as needed
     * @param i An index used to keep track of the element we are checking within the nested for loops
     * @param output The output, again, change the data type as needed
     * @param newElementOutput A String[] used to temporarily hold the elements of each String[] in the output.
     */
    private static void runThrough(String[][] input, int i, ArrayList<String[]> output, String[] newElementOutput){

        if(i < input.length - 1){
            for(String element:input[i]){
                newElementOutput[i] = element;
                runThrough(input, i+1, output, newElementOutput);
            }
        }else if(i == input.length - 1){
            for(String element:input[i]){
                newElementOutput[i] = element;
                output.add(Arrays.copyOf(newElementOutput, input.length));  // a copy so when newOutput changes, the array added to output will stay the same since the reference is different
            }
        }
    }

    public static void getCombinations(String[][] input, boolean printTest){
        String[] newOutput = new String[input.length];
        ArrayList<String[]> output = new ArrayList<>();
        runThrough(input, 0, output, newOutput);

        // Print the results, to check that everything is as it should
        if (printTest) printResults(output);
    }

    private static void printResults(ArrayList<String[]> output){
        System.out.println("Combinations:\n");
        for(String[] test:output){
            for(String combination:test){
                System.out.print(combination);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        /*
        Since in the given example there are four sets of 2, 4, 2 and 1 elements, respectively,
        there should be 2 * 4 * 2 * 1 = 16 different combinations
        */
        System.out.println("\nTotal number of combinations: " + output.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] arr = {
            {"a", "b"},
            {"c", "d", "e", "f"},
            {"g", "h"},
            {"i"}};
        getCombinations(arr, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this I think this solve your problem

```
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String a[]) {
            List<List<String>> lists = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("a", "b"), Arrays.asList("c", "d", "e", "f"), Arrays.asList("g", "h"), Arrays.asList("i"));
            System.out.println("lists = " + lists);
            List<List<String>> out = getOutPut(new ArrayList<>(), lists);
            System.out.println("out = " + out);
        }

        private static List<List<String>> getOutPut(List<String> conList, List<List<String>> lists) {
            List<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<>();
            if (lists.size() == 1) {
                lists.get(0).forEach(s -> {
                    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(conList);
                    newList.add(s);
                    out.add(newList);
                });
            } else {
                lists.get(0).forEach(s -> {
                    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(conList);
                    newList.add(s);
                    out.addAll(getOutPut(newList, lists.subList(1, lists.size())));
                });
            }
            return out;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used the data type as String but you can optimize this in generic way